# How to revert date DD/MM/YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD?

Tags: javascript, html, json, regex

How can I transform a simple string of date format from `DD/MM/YYYY` to `YYYY-MM-DD` using regex?

Comment: Is this just a string or is it a `Date`? What have you tried? Have you looked into libraries like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)? We aren't going to just do everything for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `regex` along with `replace()` method to achieve your result easily.

`Regex` are quite helpful in these cases.

```
 var yourString = "16/05/2017";
 var desired = yourString.replace(/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/, "$3-$2-$1");
```

**Explanation of the above pattern**

In the above `regex`;

> > `\d` - matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
> >
> > `{1, 2}` - checked either for 1 or 2 times[since days and months can be 1 digit(e.g. 1)or 2 digits(e.g. 01) only]
> >
> > `{4}` - checked for exactly 4 times(you can alter it accordingly)
> >
> > `^` - asserts position at start of the string
> >
> > `$` -  asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)
> >
> > In the second(replacing) String the `$3`, `$2` or `$1` represents the order of the regex(the one mentioned earlier) followed by hyphen(`-`) and that is what you are expecting.

You can also test the above pattern in [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/VYfKxn/3) or the whole code in [**here**](https://repl.it/@mAndY80SS/ActualEnchantedWheel).

Regards :)

Comment: This will match a string but how can it be used to transform as string? That's what the question is asking.

Comment: Best answer :) i got you.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite simple:

`yourString.split('/').reverse().join('-')`

The `split` part will make an Array with the numbers in the order they first appear.

The `reverse` will change the order, in your case from `day`, `month`, `year` to `year`, `month`, `day`

The `join` will turn the array into a string, using the `'-'` separator.

Comment: nah he changed the order of the numbers as well

Comment: Perhaps you could include a small explanation for *why* this works.

Comment: @TKoL Right. They reversed them. Like what this answer does.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the string on the `/` character and reassembling it in the correct format:

```
var dateString = '16/05/2017'; // to format "2017-05-16"
var nums = dateString.split('/');
var newDateString = `${nums[2]}-${nums[1]}-${nums[0]}`
console.log(newDateString)
```